# Image brightness quantification

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to quantify the brightness of an image with 1 parameter as I would like to follow the changes of brightness over a longer period of time.

One option is to convert the image in grayscale and then calculate the histogram of that image. When the number of pixels with higher values increases, the images get brighter, but I would need to somehow define a single parameter so that it would be easy to follow the progress.

I was thinking about adding together the products of all the the pixel value ranges and the number of pixels in that range. As the bightness would increase this sum should increase.

Is there already a standardised parameter for image brightness?

Comment: Mean of intensity over all pixels in the grayscale image!?

Comment: @HansHirse I was thinking the same...

Comment: If the image will get brighter, the intensity should increase, this makes sense. Thanks!